# O que faz a expressão "!(errS&errE)" no if?

Tags: c, if, operadores

Em uma parte de um código que preciso entender, apareceu uma sintaxe nova para mim no `if`:

```
if (!(errS&errE)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nFALTA ARGUMENTOS\n");
    if(!errS)
        fprintf(stderr, "-s NOME ARQUIVO SAIDA \n");
    if(!errE)
        fprintf(stderr, "-e NOME ARQUIVO ENTRADA \n");
    exit(1);
```

`errS` e `errE` são variáveis, mas não entendi qual a condição que deve ser satisfeita. O uso do `!` é estranho para mim. Sei que `!=` é diferente, mas apenas `!` não conheço. O que significa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos escrever o código de forma mais legível:

```
if (!(errS & errE)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nFALTA ARGUMENTOS\n");
    if (!errS) fprintf(stderr, "-s NOME ARQUIVO SAIDA \n");
    if (!errE) fprintf(stderr, "-e NOME ARQUIVO ENTRADA \n");
    exit(1);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/AndBit.c).

Embora neste caso funciona considero a primeira expressão avaliada um erro.

O operador `&`, nesse contexto, faz uma "multiplicação" de bits. Então ele pega o número contida em cada uma das variáveis e testa individualmente cada um deles resultando em 1 apenas quando o bit analisado é 1 nas duas variáveis ao mesmo tempo. Como provavelmente você tem uma variável atual como *flag* e os únicos valores possíveis devem ser 0 e 1 nessas variáveis, funciona, porque só o bit menos significativo varia, todos os outros são sempre 0.

Mas se essa variável vir a ter outros valores diferentes de 0 e 1, e a tipagem permite isto, já não funcionaria, ou pior, em alguns casos funcionaria e outros não. Já seria algo confuso para um programador experiente, imagine para um iniciante. Por isso é melhor usar a semântica correta sempre. Neste caso seria.

```
if (!(errS && errE))
```

Assim o número será garantidamente convertido para 1 quando ele for diferente de 0.

Então o resultado da expressão interna só será 1 quando as duas variáveis sejam diferente de 0.

O `!` é um inversor de resultado booleano. Então se o resultado da expressão entre parênteses for 1, ele considerará o resultado geral como 0 e se o resultado parcial for 0, o final será 1.

O mesmo vale para as outras expressões mais simples em que a inversão já ocorre direto na variável. Se a variável valer 0 o resultado será 12, se a variável valer qualquer coisa diferente de 0 o resultado será 0.

Lembrando que o `if` executa sempre que o resultado final da expressão contida na sua condição seja 1. também lembrando que a condição é uma expressão qualquer, até mesmo um `if (1)` pode ser usado, claro que sem sentido porque o `if` executaria sempre. Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa não precisa ter uma comparação dentro da condição do `if`, precisa ter um valor booleano, ou seja, ou 0, ou 1, como ele será obtido é outra questão.

Answer (score 0):

Fazer `if(!errS)` é o mesmo que `if(errS == 0)`, se por exemplo o tipo da variável `errS` for `int`. Quer dizer que a variavel `errS` está vazia. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Mas e o "if (!(errS&errE))" ? Quer dizer if(errS == errE)?

Comment: Nao , quer dizer if(errS == 0 && errE == 0) ou if(!errS && !errR) .

Comment: "Quer dizer que a variável `errS` está vazia" - vazia é um termo vago/ambíguo para um inteiro. Melhor é dizer que tem `0` mesmo.

Comment: O operador `&` não é igual ao operador `&&`. O primeiro é para bit a bit ("bitwise"), o segundo para operações lógicas. https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Operadores#Operadores_L%C3%B3gicos_Bit_a_Bit